# Promise.all in JavaScript: How to get resolve value for all promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

I wrote the following node.js file:

```
var csv = require('csv-parser');
var fs = require('fs')
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var filename = "devices.csv";
var devices;

Promise.all(read_csv_file("devices.csv"), read_csv_file("bugs.csv")).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});


function read_csv_file(filename) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var result = []
            fs.createReadStream(filename)
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', function (data) {
                    result.push(data)
                }).on('end', function () {
                resolve(result);
            });
    })
}
```

As you can see, I use `Promise.all` in order to wait for both operations of reading the csv files. I don't understand why but when I run the code the line `'console.log(result)'` is not committed.

My second question is I want that the callback function of `Promise.all.then()` accepts two different variables, while each one of them is the result of the relevant promise.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**First question**

`Promise.all` takes an array of promises

Change:

```
Promise.all(read_csv_file("devices.csv"), read_csv_file("bugs.csv"))
```

to (add `[]` around arguments)

```
Promise.all([read_csv_file("devices.csv"), read_csv_file("bugs.csv")])
// ---------^-------------------------------------------------------^
```

**Second question**

The `Promise.all` resolves with an array of results for each of the promises you passed into it.

This means you can extract the results into variables like:

```
Promise.all([read_csv_file("devices.csv"), read_csv_file("bugs.csv")])
  .then(function(results) {
    var first = results[0];  // contents of the first csv file
    var second = results[1]; // contents of the second csv file
  });
```

You can use ES6+ [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to further simplify the code:

```
Promise.all([read_csv_file("devices.csv"), read_csv_file("bugs.csv")])
  .then(function([first, second]) {

  });
```

Comment: thanks. And what about my second question? Now, result includes all the data from both files. How can get each file's data to a separate array?

Answer (score 2):

### Answer to your second question:

If you want the `then` callback to accept two different arguemnts, then you can use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) and its `spread` method. See:

- http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html

Instead of `.then(function (array) { ... })` and having to access `array[0]` and `array[1]` inside of your `then` handler you will be able to use `spread(function (value1, value2) { ... })` and have both variables named as you want.

This is a feature of Bluebird, it's not possible with plain `Promise`.

You use Bluebird just like Promise, e.g.:

```
var P = require('bluebird');
// and in your code:
return new P(function (resolve, reject) { ...
// instead of:
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { ...
```

Of course you don't have to name it `P` but whatever you want.

For more examples see the [Bluebird Cheatsheets](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/bluebird.html).

Comment: thanks. Isn't there any way to do it without bluebird ?

Comment: @CrazySynthax No. A standard Promise has only `then` which gets an array for Promise.all.

Comment: and if I use 'spread', how is error handling being committed? I didn't see a catch clause in the link.

Comment: @CrazySynthax You use `.spread(...).catch(...)` just like you would `.then(...).catch(...)`.

Comment: @CrazySynthax See the [Bluebird cheatsheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/bluebird.html)